# Splitting a string by a repeated regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I would like to parse text and separate it into tasks and subtasks:

```
'Asubsubsubtask:Bsubtask:Ctask:D'.split(/((sub)*task)\:/i)
#=> ["A", "subsubsubtask", "sub", "B", "subtask", "sub", "C", "task", "D"]
```

The last part of the result array is not consistent and doesn't allow me to use `#each_slice(3)` processing the array.

What would you suggest me to use instead of matching each element of the array with a similar regex?

EDIT1:

More detailed example:

```
Task: Main
description
Defaults: some params

Subtask: Basic
description
Options: A B C

Subsubtask: Reading
description
Parameters: some params
```

and I try to split it by `/^((sub)*task)\:/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate it into two `split` calls:

```
irb(main):007:0> 'Asubsubsubtask:Bsubtask:Ctask:D'.split(':').collect{|s| s.split(/((sub)*task)/i)}
=> [["A", "subsubsubtask", "sub"], ["B", "subtask", "sub"], ["C", "task"], ["D"]]
```

Comment: @marcog, thanks! There are other keywords in my text, which I would like to parse after splitting into tasks. General form `/^([a-z])\:/i`

Comment: @Andrei Where are the other keywords? Please give an example.

Comment: @marcog, Just did it. Please, see the updated question! I think I better split by `task` and then each of them by `(sub)*task` - then the problem resolves.

Comment: @Andrei And what do you want to get out? (Side note: Please ask what you really need help with from the beginning. Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)).

Comment: @marcog, I was just surprised by getting `"C", "task", "D"` instead of `"C", "task", "", "D"`.

Comment: @Andrei The reason for that is `(task):` (in `...Ctask:D`) matches as a separator. This returns the token `task` because it's in a group, then splits `...Ctask:D` into `...C` and `D`.